# React native fetching data from secured API's endpoint with JWT

Tags: react-native, jwt, fetch, axios

I'm developing React Native application which is connected to Web API written in ASP.NET Core 2.1. I'm trying to make GET request to my secured API's endpoint, but it doesn't work both with *fetch* and *axios*.

Noteworthy is fact, when I make request to unsecured (marked as AllowAnonymous) endpoint, everything works fine.

I'm passing following header `'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + MY_TOKEN`

When I tried to use *axios*, then it returned HTTP 401. When using *fetch* it returns HTTP 500.

```
 const url = `${baseUrl}/api/cars/get`

 fetch(url, {
        headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: "Bearer <MY_TOKEN_HERE>"
        }), method: "GET"
    })
```

I'm sure the token is valid because I am able to get data from API with Postman and with .NET Core console application client.

Is there any way to get the data from secured API's endpoint?

Comment: What's the response?

Comment: Look at the error messages logged in the browser devtools console

Comment: Yes, I checked the message in console. As I mentioned, it gives me 401 status code when using axios. No error message, Just 401. Passing token using postman works perfectly. I have no idea why it doesnt  work when using axios/fetch

Comment: Try with Postman (or the .NET Core console application client) sending an OPTIONS request to the same URL, without the Authorization request header added

Comment: Just tried with Postman, and works as it should - without Authorization request header I'm getting 401.

Comment: See my below answer. Issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with just one line of code.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
```

Then I am able to invoke the get request.

```
const url = `${baseUrl}/api/values`;

axios.get(url)
    .then(data => {
         console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {

    })
```

Hope it helps someone who will have such issue in the future.